# Can we not compare strings with carriage return \r?

Tags: arrays, c, string, string-comparison, carriage-return

I am trying to compare array of string with single string using `strcmp()` function. When I use strings without `\r` carriage return, it works fine as expected, but when I use carriage return, it does not compare. Why?

Here is the code with `\r`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>         // For EXIT_SUCCESS & EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    const char response[8][4]   =    {"DD1\r","DD2\r","DR1\r","DR2\r","SE1\r","SE2\r","SD1\r","SD2\r"};
    char *s                     =   "SD1\r";
    int i   =   0;
    int k   =   0;
    while(1)
    {
        k   =   strcmp(*(response+i),s);
        i++;
        if(k==0)
        {
            printf("Match Found\t%d\n",k);
            fflush(stdout);
            break;
        }
        if(i>12)
            break;
        printf("%d\t",i);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
```

And here is the code without the `\r`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>         // For EXIT_SUCCESS & EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    const char response[8][4]   =    {"DD1\r","DD2\r","DR1\r","DR2\r","SE1\r","SE2","SD1\r","SD2\r"};
    char *s                     =   "SE2";
    int i   =   0;
    int k   =   0;
    while(1)
    {
        k   =   strcmp(*(response+i),s);
        i++;
        if(k==0)
        {
            printf("Match Found\t%d\n",k);
            fflush(stdout);
            break;
        }
        if(i>12)
            break;
        printf("%d\t",i);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   Match Found 0
```

Can we not compare strings with \r?

Comment: If one of the strings contains `\r` and the other does not, then `strcmp` returns non-zero.  `strcmp` will return 0 only if the strings match. `\r` is part of the string.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `strncmp`.

Comment: This is basically a typo because your arrays represent strings, but they weren't long enough to store the nul terminator needed by string functions, thus yielding undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can indeed compare with `\r`, but the real problem lies somewhere else.

If you change the `4` to a `5` in this line:

Before:

```
const char response[8][4] = {"DD1\r","DD2\r","DR1\r","DR2\r","SE1\r","SE2\r","SD1\r","SD2\r"};
```

After:

```
const char response[8][5] = {"DD1\r","DD2\r","DR1\r","DR2\r","SE1\r","SE2\r","SD1\r","SD2\r"};
```

`strcmp` will compare as intended.

The `strcmp` function relies on the null byte being there to terminate the string. The problem with the 4 is that the string literals will get sliced off at byte 4 (`\r`). The null byte has no place to go, so to `strcmp`, `response` looks like `"DD1\rDD2\rDR1\rDR2\rSE1\rSE2\rSD1\rSD2\r"` plus whatever non-null bytes come after. String literals are always one more byte longer than what's between the quotes because of this. Therefore, at least 5 bytes are required in your case.

The reason your second code "worked" was because the 3-byte string was *not* getting sliced off, which means it was comparing as normal. In particular, it sees `response` as two separate strings:

- `"DD1\rDD2\rDR1\rDR2\rSE1\rSE2"`
- `"SD1\rSD2\r"` plus trailing non-null bytes.

#### Addendum:

If the sizes don't *have* to be fixed, this works much better:

```
const char* response[8] = {"DD1\r","DD2\r","DR1\r","DR2\r","SE1\r","SE2\r","SD1\r","SD2\r"};
```

because the compiler does the work for you.

Comment: Good spot. It's UB as soon as you pass `strcmp()` something that is not nul-terminated, so the arrays of `char` need to be 5 bytes long in either case. It only _happened_ to work when the compared string lacked the trailing `'\r'`, but it was already UB.

Comment: @underscore_d, Yeah. I tested it by printing the arguments and was racking my brain trying to figure out why there were no null bytes at the end if there was a `\r`. Then I tried other characters, and it hit me. Tricky!

Comment: This answer fails to fix the UB of accessing beyond the end of the array

Comment: ...But succeeds at answering the question.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it is working after changing size from [8][4] to [8][5]. But I read somewhere, when we use " " strings -  '\0' null byte appends to end itself. That's why I use array size as [8][4].

Comment: @TarunGarg Yes, it would append it to the end, but there's no space for it. Your strings with the `\r` are already 4 bytes long. The `\0` has to nowhere to go because you've limited the space to 4 bytes. The `\0` is a byte too:  it has to contribute to the byte count. The second suggestion with `char *` works much better because the compiler does all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. removes unused header files
2. allows the compiler to calculate sizing
3. formats the code for readability
4. eliminates unneeded variables
5. uses a `size_t` for a variable that will never by less than 0
6. uses an appropriate output format conversion specifier for the `size_t` variable
7. even if there were no match, stops when it hits the end of the data array instead of trying to access beyond the end of the array, like the OPs code does.  This avoids that undefined behavior problem.
8. limits the scope of the variable `i`
9. allows the compiler to calculate how may times to go around the loop
10. lists the data as a series of pointers to the data, rather than the undefined behavior used by the OPs code
11. performs the desired functionality

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main( void )
{
    const char *response[8]   =    
    {
        "DD1\r",
        "DD2\r",
        "DR1\r",
        "DR2\r",
        "SE1\r",
        "SE2\r",            
        "SD1\r",
        "SD2\r"
    };
    
    char *s = "SD1\r";
    
    for( size_t i=0; i< sizeof( response ) / sizeof( response[0] ); i++ )
    {
        if( ! strcmp( response[i], s ) )
        {
            printf( "Match Found\t0\n");
            break;
        }
            
        printf( "%zu\n", i );
    }
}
```

A run of the proposed code results in:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
Match Found 0
```

Comment: regarding: `2  allows the compiler to calculate sizing`  1) `for( size_t i=0; i< sizeof( response ) / sizeof( response[0] ); i++ )` has compiler calculate the number of entries in the table

Comment: regarding: `7  even if there were no match, stops when it hits the end of the data array instead of trying to access beyond the end of the array, like the OPs code does. This avoids that undefined behavior problem.`  The OPs code accesses 12 entries, but the table only contains 8 entries, so it is doing undefined behavior by accessing beyond the end of the table

Comment: regarding: `10  lists the data as a series of pointers to the data, rather than the undefined behavior used by the OPs code`  The OPs statement: `const char response[8][4]` is only allowing for 4 bytes for each entry, Which means it is ignoring the terminating '\0' of each string.  so when the statement: `k   =   strcmp(*(response+i),s);` is executed, no termination '\0' is found at the end of the 4 characters, so `strcmp()` keeps looking until it finds a '\0'.  (Naturally, no match is ever found)  The lack of a '\0' results in undefined behavior

Comment: note: I could have written: `const char *response[8]`  as `const char *response[]` which would have let the compiler calculate the number of entries (and that would be better than hardcoding the value)